Flutter await does not respond when debug as Windows app
Below is code that connects to Firebase re-authenticate function, its working in chrome/android, user is re authenticated and page is popped with 'success'. But when I run on Windows, the await part does not respond.
Upon further testing, the function is working and user is re-authenticated but it does not move to the next line and the navigator is not popped and if I remove the await function, remaining code is executed and page is popped. This happens only when I run  windows app - (Flutter - Firebase)
New Project created yesterday with the latest packages.
update: I think firebase guys missed something in their reauthenticate code since await signin, await sign out etc work as intended.
further update: with the new flutter sdk and updated packages building windows app looked promising but it seems like a distant reality for now.
final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
      await ref.read(authRepositoryProvider).reauthenticateWithCredential(
            _emailController.text.trim(),
            _passwordController.text.trim(),
          );

      setState(() {
        submitting = false;
      });

      navigator.pop('success');

